# Where can I find soil Free Swell Index values for the Cambridgeshire region, United Kingdom?

Tags: measurements, soil, field-measurements, geologic-layers, in-situ-measurements

Where can I find Free Swell Index data for Clays for the Cambridgeshire region, United Kingdom?

Surely this must have been performed at some point even though there are more sophisticated tests. I've searched the NERC Open Research Archive that includes the British Geological Survey but I have had no luck.

The Free Swell Index for soil is the easiest method for me to perform and I do not need that great accuracy but I would like some data from measurements in the Cambridgeshire region, United Kingdom for comparison. I seemed to have boulder clay (see light blue on map [Biggleswade sheet 204](https://largeimages.bgs.ac.uk/iip/mapsportal.html?id=1003300)).